# What is the use arr[s[i]-'a'] in this code and why we subtracting all characters with 'a'?

Tags: c++

Can some one explain me what is the meaning of `++arr[s[i]-'a'];` logic in the code below. Why are we subtracting each character with 'a'?

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    for(int a0 = 0; a0 < n; a0++){
        string s;
        cin >> s;
        int c=0;
        vector <int> arr(26,0);
        for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++){
            ++arr[s[i]-'a'];
        }
        for(int j=0;j<26;j++){
            if(arr[j]!=0)
            c++;
        }
        cout<<c<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific please? What is that code supposed to do? Regarding the `- 'a'` do you know the ASCII character table?

Answer (score 2):

This is a common way to convert a letter to its corresponding numerical value from 0 (for 'a') to 25 (for 'z'). Since 'a' is equal to 'a', `'a'-'a'` will be zero. Since 'b' is one greater than 'a', `'b'-'a'` will be one. And so on.

Comment: When using characters in numerical calculations, do they not correspond to their ASCII values (e.g. 'a' = 97)?

Comment: They might. It depends on the platform. All you're really guaranteed is that `a` won't be zero and that `a` through `z` will be in sequence.

Comment: `'0'`-`'9'` is guaranty to be in sequence, it is not the case for `'a'`-`'z'` or `'A'`-`'Z'`. See [EBCDIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EBCDIC) for example.

Answer (score 1):

It is using a one liner to count the number of occurrences of a letter in a word. Lets look at this broken down:

first[a[c]-'a']++;

1. a[c] - 'a' is getting the number representation of the alphabet character, so imagine if a[c] was 'b', we would get the number 1.
2. first[a[c] - 'a'] Is accessing the array first at the position of the letter.
3. first[a[c] - 'a']++ is increment the number at that position.

So if you encounter a 'b', your list will look like this:

''{0, 1, 0, ...''

Answer (score 0):

your code counting small letters in a string. For restricting only small letters -'a' used. that 26 letters only stored in vectors.